# Django. How to get fields from child model in views.py?

Tags: python, django

How to get fields from child model in `views.py`? For example, I've parent model `BasicOrder` and child model (who extends `BasicOrder`) `TouristVisa`.

I'm using Django 2.0.2 and Python 3.6.1. My `models.py` is:

```
class BasicOrder(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('User'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Status'), choices=ORDER_STATUS, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order #{}'.format(self.id)


class TouristVisa(BasicOrder, models.Model):

    citizenship = models.ForeignKey(
        Citizenship, verbose_name=_('Citizenship'), on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    invitation_entry = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        _('Invitation entry'), choices=INVITATION_ENTRY
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
```

Would be great to have access to field `invitation_entry` from child model (`TouristVisa`). I try this way in `views.py`:

```
order = BasicOrder.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
print(order.invitation_entry)
```

But it's show error:

> AttributeError: 'BasicOrder' object has no attribute 'invitation_entry'

Comment: First of all, you don't need `models.Model` in `TouristVisa` since `BasicOrder` already inherits from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wrong, when TouristVisa inherits from BasicOrder it means it gets the fields user ans status as well, not the other way around. So, you can access the invitation_entry field but calling TouristVisa also because it's the only model where it exists.

Now, access to it like this:

```
order = BasicOrder.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
print(order.touristvisa.invitation_entry)
```

Comment: One more question here: for simple fields — I understand, but how to get list from ForeignKey field (in my case `citizenship`)?

Comment: @VicShóstak Same, but instead of invitation_entry you put citizenship, and there you can access Citizenship model fields as well : order.touristvisa.citizenship.citizenship_field

Comment: How many times I can do it? For example, if I have `ModelOne(BaseModel)` with FK field to another model and that model have another FK field to another model... and I want to access field at ended model. Performance issue, if I use PostrgeSQL 9.6 (for example)? Would be great to know some `best practice` for that case :)

Comment: @VicShóstak as far as i know, there's no restriction defined, but, if you're model as too many access objects linked by foreign keys, and  i mean toooo many...you should check your model design because may not be efficient enough.